# chemformula, height of plus sign

Tags: symbols, mhchem

How do I get the plus sign to be aligned with the arrow i.e. change the height of the plus sign?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\ch[plus-space=8pt]{CH2=CH2 + 3 O2 -> 2 CO2 + 2 H2O}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you open to using the `mhchem` package instead?

Comment: I'm liking the shape of the arrows in the `chemformula` package better. If there is a way to change the shape of the arrows used in the `mhchem` package to the shapes used in `chemformula`, I'd be open to use the `mhchem` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a recent version (at least v4.9) of `chemformula` you can say:

```
\ch[plus-output-symbol = \raisebox{.2ex}{+}]{CH2=CH2 + 3 O2 -> 2 CO2 + 2 H2O}
```

You can also do the opposite (this works also with older versions):

```
\ch[arrow-yshift = -.2ex]{CH2=CH2 + 3 O2 -> 2 CO2 + 2 H2O}
```

The `.2ex` in my examples is just an initial guess…

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\setchemformula{ plus-space = .8em }

\begin{document}

\ch[plus-output-symbol = \raisebox{.2ex}{+}]{CH2=CH2 + 3 O2 -> 2 CO2 + 2 H2O}

\ch[arrow-yshift = -.2ex]{CH2=CH2 + 3 O2 -> 2 CO2 + 2 H2O}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using `mhchem` and the `arrows=pgf-filled` option (to get similar arrows). Note the option requires manual loading of the `tikz` package.

```
\documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\mhchemoptions{arrows=pgf-filled}
\begin{document}
\ce{CH2=CH2 + 3 O2 -> 2 CO2 + 2 H2O}
\end{document}
```

[image]